# Editing a sub to use string arrays combined with for each

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, foreach

I am trying to set up a bit of code to automate a task I have to do on a weekly report I run. The task is to go into all the 'data' sheets and do several find and replaces so that other parts of the report that refer to the data sheets look a bit cleaner.

Currently my code looks similar to this:

```
sub FindReplaceSheets()
  dim nameofsheet as string
  nameofsheet = "ABC Data"
  call FindReplace (nameofsheet)
  nameofsheet = "DEF Data"
  call FindReplace (nameofsheet)
End Sub

sub FindReplace (x)
  Sheets.(x).select
  Cells.Replace What:="qwerty", Replacement:="asdfgh"
  Cells.Replace What:="zxcvb", Replacement:="mnbvc"
  Cells.Replace What:="poiuy", Replacement:="lkjhg"
End Sub
```

Whilst this works fine, I am sure it can be done more neatly. There are more sheets and more find/replace than listed above but not so much that the speed of the code is vital, I am wanting to just make it look neater and be easier to edit.

I have tried to edit this in two ways: firstly to have the sheet selection done via a For each statement but I cannot get it to work with something like

```
For each ws
 If right(ws.name, 4) = "Data"
```

Secondly, I have tried to edit the find to use an array where I define each find and replace string but cannot seem to get the right syntax.

I think a string array and a for each loop would fit what I am trying to achieve here but please advise on other methods if more appropriate.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub cleanUpData()

    Dim i As Long, ws As Worksheet, dataWS As String
    Dim oldTxt      As Variant
    Dim newTxt      As Variant
    Dim firstItm    As Long
    Dim lastItm     As Long

    dataWS = " Data"

    oldTxt = Array("aaa", "bbb", "ccc")
    newTxt = Array("xxx", "yyy", "zzz")

    firstItm = LBound(oldTxt)
    lastItm = UBound(oldTxt)

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If InStr(1, ws.Name, dataWS, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            For i = firstItm To lastItm
                ws.Cells.Replace _
                    What:=oldTxt(i), _
                    Replacement:=newTxt(i), _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                    MatchCase:=False
            Next
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

.

- sheet names containing " Data" or " data" will be processed
- find and replace is also case insensitive
- use "LookAt:=xlPart" for partial matches

Comment: Thank you very much for you advice. I have tried to apply you code to my report and the find and replace part is working perfectly, thanks. Unfortunately it is not done on the worksheet required though, it will do the find and replace on what sheet I am on when I run the macro (even if that worksheet does not have "data" within it's name) and not loop into others. Most annoyingly is that it does not error so I am struggling to see what is wrong. Perhaps it completes one loop but does not get onto the next for some reason? Any advice about how I can determine what is going wrong? Thanks again!

Comment: Oh, and I actually had to make some changes. It did not like string () and errored saying it expected an end of statement so defined both 'oldtxt' and 'newtxt' as variant instead - could that be where the problem lies.

Comment: thanks for the feedback - my intent was to proide you a solution that requires minimal changes, but I was working without access to Excel (new Windows install). I'll check (and test) the code, and get back to you shortly

Comment: Hi  again Paul. Thanks so much for your help, through trying to bug fix this small bit of code I feel like I have learnt quite a bit. However, the code is still not working correctly. If I go through the code in break mode then the code will cycle through each sheet, skipping the find/replace bit when sheet does not have data in the name, but will only ever make find/replace changes in the active worksheet I am in when running code. Hovering over .name within the instr func will say 'abc data' but the find replace will happen in abc (if that was the sheet I was active in). any ideas? thanks

Comment: you did the right thing monitoring it in break mode - that's how you get to see the properties and methods available for the objects used. but I'm not sure why it;s not working on your machine; is there any way you could share your monitor? if not, you're on the right path: you'll have to look at the sheet name when going through the loop.  when it gets to the line with  "InStr(1, .Name, dataWS, vbTextCompare)"  hold the mouse over ".Name" first and the name of the current sheet will pop up in a tool-tip, then you can highlight the line itself and add it the "watch" window, to see the result

Comment: I can also send you the test file I used when adjusting the final code to see if it runs ok for you (I used Excel 2007 64 bit); you'll find my email on flickr: https://www.flickr.com/people/dexxus/

Comment: thanks for the reply Paul. I asked a colleague if they had any idea and in the end changing two parts of your code got it to work. within the InStr func I used 'ws.name' rather than '.name' and within the statement for the fin/replace I used 'cells.replace' rather than '.usedrange.replace'. not sure why the differences were needed, perhaps working from a different version of Excel? Whatever the case, I appreciate your help, thanks

Comment: great work! and thanks for letting me know - basically it lost the references sheet and range in the loop for some reason, so I'll update the code to eliminate similar issues

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub FindReplaceSheets(sheetNamesArray As Variant, findTextArray As Variant, replaceWithTextArray As Variant)
Dim sheetName

For Each sheetName In sheetNamesArray
    If Right(sheetName, 4) = "data" Then
        Call FindReplace(sheetName, findTextArray, replaceWithTextArray)
    End If
Next
End Sub
Sub FindReplace(ByVal sheetName As String, findTextArray As Variant, replaceWithTextArray As Variant)
Dim i As Integer
Dim count As Integer

count = UBound(findTextArray)
Sheets(sheetName).Select

For i = 0 To count
  Cells.Replace What:=findTextArray(i), Replacement:=replaceWithTextArray(i)
Next
End Sub
```

Here is how you make a call to the procedure above

```
call FindReplaceSheets(Array("Sheet1Data", "Sheet2Data"), Array("findtext1", "findtext2"), Array("replacetext1", "replacetext2"))
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply! I have updated my code to match your suggestion and I get a mismatch error. Do I have to define/fill out the sheetnames array before going into the for each loop do I?

Answer (score 0):

Make an array and use a loop:

```
Sub FindReplaceSheets()
   ary = Split("ABC Data,DEF Data", ",")

   For Each a In ary
      Call FindReplace(a)
   Next a
End Sub
```